# How to extract data with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, extract

Hello I am trying to extract the odds of this webpage : https://www.netbet.fr/derniere-minute?filter=13

Here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.netbet.fr/derniere-minute?filter=13')

odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "nb-odds_amount")]')))]

print(odds, '\n')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The output gives me that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./azerty.py", line 31, in <module>
    odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "nb-odds_amount")]')))]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This script run perfectly with other webpage but not in this case. Some help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some elements are hidden and that's where the issue occurs. You wait until ALL elements are visible `visibility_of_all_elements_located` while some elements are hidden, so you will wait infinitely. Try waiting for presence instead of visibility to go around that issue `presence_of_all_elements_located`

```
odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "nb-odds_amount")]')))]
```